# Filtering data with __range

Tags: python, django, filter, range

I'm using `django_tables2` thus part of the code is dependent on this package, but this should be irrelevant to the overall problem.

`forms.py`

```
class PersonForm(forms.Form):
    date_from = forms.DateField(input_formats='%d/%m/%Y')
    date_to = forms.DateField(input_formats='%d/%m/%Y')
```

`views.py`

```
def filter(request):
    table = PersonTable(Person.objects.all())
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = PersonForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            date_from = form.cleaned_data['date_from']
            date_to = form.cleaned_data['date_to']
            result_filtered = table.filter(date__range=(date_from, date_to))

            RequestConfig(request, paginate={"per_page": 100}).configure(table)
            return render(request, "people.html", {
                         "table": result_filtered })

    args = {}
    args.update(csrf(request))
    args['form'] = PersonForm()
    args['table'] = table
    RequestConfig(request, paginate={"per_page": 100}).configure(table)
    return render(request, 'people.html', args)
```

Simply, filtering is not working. I can see the entire table, but when I try to filter nothing happens. Can you see what's wrong?

Comment: Why are you using POST to do filtering? POST is ment for data alteration or addition, filtering should use GET. Also, your code is too repetitive, don't do two different returns. You don't need to.

Comment: Are you sure your form is valid?  If it fails the `is_valid` check, it'll fall through to create a new form instance and therefore not show any form errors.

Comment: Alright, I changed to GET but this does nothing. Yes, I think it is valid.

Comment: Well, make sure of that - change your code to render the bound form when it's not valid.  Also, I suspect you're calling `RequestConfig` on the wrong object when the form is valid, but I am not familiar enough with django-tables2 to tell whether that's the cause of your problem.

Comment: Well, you nailed it - the form is not valid. Can you elaborate how to tweak it?

Comment: It depends on how you changed it to use GET - how are you distinguishing between requests that include form data and those that don't?

Comment: I told you to use GET because that's a convention of web development, it obviously doesn't change the problem. I'm not that familiar with django_tables2 to be frank, so I can't say for sure what you are doing wrong, though I would maybe try changing the context to `'mytable': result_filtered` because maybe the package is already using the `{{ table }}` and it's clashing somehow

Comment: also, use prints and look in the shell the runs the development server. It's a great tool to debug (for example, you could do a `print 'form is valid yay!'` after the `if form.is_valid` to see that yes, the form is actually validating, instead of hoping it is, and so on...)

Comment: @PeterDeGlopper, I just changed every `POST` to `GET`. For the second part of the question, I'm not really sure, I've mixed up some tutorials to come up with the code and what's happening under the hood I kinda magic to me.

Comment: That won't quite work with the usual Django patterns for using forms.  I'll put in an answer showing how I'd do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one way I'd do it, assuming your `Person` model has a `date` field:

```
def filter(request):
    if 'date_from' in request.GET and 'date_to' in request.GET:
        # form data has been submitted
        form = PersonForm(request.GET)
        if form.is_valid():
            date_from = form.cleaned_data['date_from']
            date_to = form.cleaned_data['date_to']
            people = Person.objects.filter(date__range=(date_from, date_to))
            table = PersonTable(people)
        else:
            table = PersonTable(Person.objects.all())
    else:
        form = PersonForm()
        table = PersonTable(Person.objects.all())
    RequestConfig(request, paginate={"per_page": 100}).configure(table)
    args = {}
    args.update(csrf(request))
    args['form'] = form
    args['table'] = table
    return render(request, 'people.html', args)
```

This binds the form if both its expected fields are present, and limits the queryset according to the results if valid.  If not valid, it renders the bound form and the table built from the unlimited table.  If form data was not submitted, it renders the table built from the unlimited table.

Your form tag's `method` attribute should be `GET` rather than `POST`, if using this design.

This doesn't quite follow the usual Django patterns for form handling because the form isn't actually making any changes, so you can use `GET` and don't need to return a redirect on success.

Comment: Thank you very much! We're almost there :) It filters some ranges and some it does not. It filters currectly when I put different years eg. from `01/10/2009` to `01/10/2010` but it fails (shows the entire table again) with days and months eg. from `01/10/2009` to `03/10/2009` or `01/10/2009` to `01/11/2009`

Comment: For that the first thing to check is that there really are values - bearing in mind that with the input format you've defined `01/10/2009` is October 1, 2009 and not January 10 - so a range of `01/10/2009` to `03/10/2009` is only three days.

Comment: 3days, I know. Anyway, this seems to be date format issue. Now I've removed `input_formats` from forms to use the default and it worked out when I inserted the dates in format `10/01/2009` (m/d/Y) to `10/03/2009`. Thank you again!

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure you need to call `.filter()` on the query set rather than the table. For example:

```
result_filtered = PersonTable(Person.objects.filter(date__range=(date_from, date_to))
```

Also, on this line:

```
RequestConfig(request, paginate={"per_page": 100}).configure(table)
```

You are passing in `table`. You should pass in `result_filtered` instead.

Comment: table is a query set already `table = PersonTable(Person.objects.all())`. Thanks for the `.configure()` tip though. overall it's still unsolved.

Comment: The point is that `table` is a `PersonTable` object, which although it can be created from data taken from a queryset is not itself a queryset and does not have a `filter` method.  Once you get the form to be valid, this will also need to be corrected.

Comment: @jproffitt you seem familiar with `django_tables2`. Have you used it and filtered tables?

Comment: Yes I have used django tables2 extensively. And yes I have filtered the results with it as well. I always filter the query set before passing it into the table like I mentioned.

Comment: Have you posted any code online by chance? I'd just like to get some feel how to filter them in general.

Comment: No publicly available code... but Peter DeGlopper's Solution is exactly how I was expecting to do it.